# Segmentation fault when using OpenCv fisheye::calibrate() function

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, camera-calibration

I'm using the fisheye::calibrate() function from OpenCv 2.4.10 (C++ API) to calibrate a fisheye camera. When I use the standard cv::calibrateCamera() function for pinhole camera everything works correctly. If I use the fisheye counterpart (i.e. fisheye::calibrate()) with the **same inputs** (the two functions have the same signature) I get a segmentation fault error. 
Is this a known issue? What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's been a while since this was submitted, but as I stumbled across this trying to solve the same problem I'll put the solution I found here to help those that follow.

It looks like there is a bug with this function which means it cannot cope with Mat parameters for input and output arrays. When I used the following signature it started working.

```
double cv::fisheye::calibrate (vector<vector<Point3f> > objectPoints, vector<vector<Point2f> > imagePoints, const Size &image_size, Matx33d K, Vec4d D, vector<Vec3d> rvecs, vector<Vec3d> tvecs, int flags=0, TermCriteria criteria=TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT+TermCriteria::EPS, 100, DBL_EPSILON))
```

Thankfully the Mat type has some good methods for doing the conversions, so in my case (where I already had imagePoints in the right format anyhow) I was just able to do:

```
distCoeffs = Mat::zeros(4, 1, CV_64F);
Matx33d tempCameraMatrix = cameraMatrix;
Vec4d tempDistCoeffs = distCoeffs;
```

I hope that helps someone out there!